# Error with sampleapp supplied with windowsSDK evernote

Tags: vb.net, evernote

```
' Download the thumbnail for a note; then display it on this app's form.
Dim thumbnail As Byte() = ENSession.SharedSession.DownloadThumbnailForNote(myResultsList(0).NoteRef, 120)
Try
    Dim ms As New MemoryStream(thumbnail, 0, thumbnail.Length)
    ms.Position = 0
    Dim image1 As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms, False, False)
 
    PictureBoxThumbnail.Image = image1
Catch ex As Exception
    Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
End Try

' Display a note's content as HTML in a WebBrowser control.
Dim myContent = myDownloadedNote.HtmlContent
WebBrowser1.DocumentText = myContent
End If
```

with these 2 blocks of code from the included "Sampleapp"

i am getting the following errors....

> Error    1    'PictureBoxThumbnail' is not declared. It may be
> inaccessible due to its protection level.
> H:\Michael-Documents\Visual Studio
> 2013\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Form1.vb    84
> 17    WindowsApplication1
>
> Error    2    'WebBrowser1' is not declared. It may be inaccessible
> due to its protection level.    H:\Michael-Documents\Visual Studio
> 2013\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Form1.vb    91
> 13    WindowsApplication1

could anyone give me a helping hand, as to what is wrong. Sometimes the Head does not want to think. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This sample app from the Evernote Windows SDK consists of a form with two controls on it named PictureBoxThumbnail and WebBrowser1. I checked the relevant code on Github and confirmed that they are there in the VB.NET SDK sample.

It sounds like somehow in the copy of the app you have in your Visual Studio, the names of these controls have been altered, or the controls may not be on the form at all.

Double-click on the form ("Form1") in the VS Solution Explorer window so as to open it in the VS Designer. There should be one PictureBox control on the left-hand side, named PictureBoxThumbnail, and one larger WebBrowser control on the right-hand side named WebBrowser1. If you don't have either or both of these controls on your form, add them; or if they are not named PictureBoxThumbnail and WebBrowser1, respectively, then rename them to those names. Then the app should run properly.

Comment: how do i add a large reply, this comment box, does not allow large replys.?

Comment: this is line 43         Dim myFile As Byte() = StreamFile("H:\WSR_Photography\JPEG\WSRP08.JPEG")    ' Be sure to replace this with a real JPG file

Comment: Please provide the exact error message that you're getting.